# How to disable the effect of increasing the label in TabBar Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I click on a tab in tabbar, the effect of increasing the label occurs. 
I want to disable this effect.

[image]

In MainPage.xaml

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="App1.MainPage"
            xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:App1;assembly=App1"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            android:TabbedPage.IsSwipePagingEnabled="False"
            BarBackgroundColor ="White" IsHidden="True"
            SelectedTabColor="#ad1457">

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="Four" BarBackgroundColor = "#ffffff"  BarTextColor="Black" Icon="icon1.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local1:Page1 />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

        <NavigationPage Title = "Five" BarBackgroundColor = "#ffffff"  BarTextColor="Black" Icon="icon1.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local1:Page2 />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

        <NavigationPage Title = "Six" BarBackgroundColor = "#ffffff"  BarTextColor="Black" Icon="icon1.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local1:Page3 />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        On<Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
    }
```

Comment: Can u share us ur code?

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW 
Added code. There is nothing special about the code. This is the standard tabbedPage.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 textviews if it is `BottomNavigationView`( i.e when `ToolbarPlacement.Bottom`)
By default when its selected it has higher fontsize.
You need to set the same size for both `TextView`s in either custom renderer or [Platform Effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction).

Here is the code

```cs
{
    if (!(Container.GetChildAt(0) is ViewGroup layout))
        return;

    if (!(layout.GetChildAt(1) is BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView))
        return;

    var bottomNavMenuView = bottomNavigationView.GetChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView;

    for (int i = 0; i < bottomNavMenuView.ChildCount; i++)
    {
        var item = bottomNavMenuView.GetChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView;
        var itemTitle = item.GetChildAt(1);

        var smallTextView = ((TextView)((BaselineLayout)itemTitle).GetChildAt(0));
        var largeTextView = ((TextView)((BaselineLayout)itemTitle).GetChildAt(1));

        smallTextView.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Sp, 8);// this is unselected textview size
        largeTextView.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Sp, 8); //this is selected textview size
    }
 }
```

Comment: There is such a strange twitching effect.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiPLL.gif

Comment: Do you disable the shifemode for `TabbedPage` in custom renderer.?

Comment: Yes, the shift effect is disabled.

Comment: That's not related to label. You can try updating the layout parameters of icon. It's first child of `BottomNavigationItemView` i.e var item

Comment: Please mark your answer, it will help others who have similar issue.